# Returning zero nodes in realtime startAt query

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Im trying to make pagination with Realtime db. I am making query first time with limit 15 and second time based on last item uid i am making second query where suppose to startAt() with that uid. After first query I am receiving as it suppose to 15 items. Next time it suppose to send me back 9 items. But it sends me zero

The code of response

```
 DatabaseReference mReference = realtimeReference.child("OnlineUsers/" + neededGender);

    Query query;
    if (uid.equals("")){
        query = mReference.orderByChild("rating").limitToLast(TOTAL_ITEMS_TO_LOAD);
    }else {
        //Pagination query with last uid to start
        query = mReference.orderByChild("rating").startAt(uid).limitToLast(TOTAL_ITEMS_TO_LOAD);
    }
    query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            final List<OnlineUser> userList = new ArrayList<>();
            for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                OnlineUser user = postSnapshot.getValue(OnlineUser.class);
                userList.add(new OnlineUser(user.getUid(), user.getName(), user.getImage(), user.getGender(), user.getCountry(), user.getRating()));
            }
            EventBus.getDefault().post(new ListEvent(userList));
        }
```

Database structure
[image]

Comment: You apply `startAt` on **rating** instead of **uid**

Comment: @Md.Asaduzzaman you means change the place? i tried `            query = mReference.startAt(uid).orderByChild("rating").limitToLast(TOTAL_ITEMS_TO_LOAD);` but again zero

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When paginating, you always need to pass the **value** of the property that you order on. In addition, if there are multiple nodes with the same value for that property, you *should* pass the **key** of of the first item to return.

So in your case that'd be:

```
mReference.orderByChild("rating").startAt(rating, key).limitToLast(TOTAL_ITEMS_TO_LOAD);
```

This assumes that you have the rating of the node in `rating` and its key in `key`.

Comment: do i understand right that instead of making startAt(uid) i need to pass last item rating value?

Comment: as I understand from google tutorial with query it suppose to get a reference first then sort it by child and based on result it has to send back result with needed portions.

Comment: Since the API is `startAt`, you pass in the value and key of the node to start at. But since you're using it for pagination, you're typically passing in the value/key of the last node of the previous page, and retrieve one extra item.

Comment: Im sorry. Dont get it for 100%. So my query will be `query =mReference.orderByKey().startAt("uid",uid).limitToLast(TOTAL_ITEMS_TO_LOAD);` ? where first uid is key of the field and second uid is value uid of the last item?

Comment: I have tried `query =mReference.orderByKey().startAt(uid,"uid").limitToLast(TOTAL_ITEMS_TO_LOAD);` but app crashed with `    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You must use startAt(String value), endAt(String value) or equalTo(String value) in combination with orderByKey(). Other type of values or using the version with 2 parameters is not supported`

Comment: No, not at all, I didn't mention `orderByKey` because your first query orders on `rating`. If your first item has a rating of `4` and your last key was `gCHU8...7wd2`, you'd build a query that starts at: `mReference.orderByChild("rating").startAt(4, "gCHU8...7wd2")`.